# Multiple xsl:choose within a single xsl:when

Tags: xml, xslt

If I am testing several different defined parameters can I call multiple `xsl:when` statements within on `xsl:choose` statement? So if I have:

```
<parameters>
                    <param id="1">
                        <key>Load</key>
                        <value>XML</value>
                    </param>
                    <param id="2">
                        <key>Input</key>
                        <value>Http</value>
                    </param>
                    <param id="3">
                        <key>Response</key>
                        <value>Y</value>
                    </param> 
</parameters>
```

could I call three different `<xsl:when>` with a single `<xsl:choose>` to check the  because I will have several `<param>` with different `<value>` that will later need to help call different templates.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a different approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, sure, you can. You can also add an `xsl:otherwise` node to handle all other cases:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="param/@id = '1'">
        <xsl:text>XML</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="param/@id = '2'">
        <xsl:text>HTTP</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="param/@id = '3'">
        <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>Other format</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

This is similar to the `switch` statement in C-like languages and Java, or the `Select Case` in VB.

Of course, you can check for arbitrary XPath expressions, e.g. you could check as well for

```
<xsl:when test="param/key = 'Input'">
    <!-- handle input -->
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Is each <xsl:when> mutually exclusive? So if all three tests were true, would only the first be chosen?

Comment: yes, they are mutually exclusive - refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742988/when-to-use-xslif-and-when-to-use-xslchoose-xslwhen-in-xslt (Answer of Damien_The_Unbeliever). The first match will apply.

Answer (score 4):

> could I call three different
>    with a single 
>   to check the because I will have
>   several  with different 
>   that will later need to help call
>   different templates.

Yes, you can and @0xA3 showed you how.

**But you needn't and shouldn't!**

It is in the spirit of XSLT that the XSLT processor can decide what template to apply on what condition.

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="param[@id=1]">
    Load!
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="param[@id=2]">
    Input!
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="param[@id=3]">
    Response!
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<parameters>
    <param id="1">
        <key>Load</key>
        <value>XML</value>
    </param>
    <param id="2">
        <key>Input</key>
        <value>Http</value>
    </param>
    <param id="3">
        <key>Response</key>
        <value>Y</value>
    </param>
</parameters>
```

**produces:**

```
<parameters>
    Load!

    Input!

    Response!
 </parameters>
```

**Do note that we didn't use any conditional logic** -- the XSLT processor itself decided which template to apply for the `<param>` elements with different `id` attributes.

This is a great facility(in this concrete case you saved 14 lines of code that is error-prone) and is recommended to be used as often as possible