# when to use xsl:if and when to use xsl:choose/xsl:when in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I know this may seem like a dumb/newbie question, but I'm fairly new to *XSLT* (though I'm starting to come around to it and see it's capabilities).

When is it appropriate to use **xsl:if** and when is it appropriate to use **xsl:choose/xsl:when**?

I have been using choose/when/otherwise when I want to have an "else" option. Is this correct?

For instance I have some places where I'm doing:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="count(entry) != 0">
    put positive outcome here
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    put something else here
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

would xsl:if be better?

Thanks for the input.

Comment: What other languages are you familiar with?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have a .net background mostly in vb though I can do c# as well as html, javascript, php, perl (from back in the day) and cold fusion

Answer (score 6):

Use `xsl:if` for simple cases where you just want to test if an expression is true. (Note that there is no corresponding `xsl:else`.)

```
<xsl:if test="expression">
    output if the expression is true
</xsl:if>
```

Use `xsl:choose` for cases where you have some alternate output when the expressions is false.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="expression">
        output if the expression is true
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        output if the expression is false
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 4):

> would xsl:if be better?

Not really - unless you want to have two `xsl:if`s and ensure that their conditions are mutually exclusive.

an [`xsl:choose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256169.aspx) will always select exactly *one* of the available `xsl:when` or `xsl:otherwise`

> The `<xsl:when>` children of the `<xsl:choose>` element are tested, in order from top to bottom, until a test attribute on one of these elements accurately describes conditions in the source data, or until an `<xsl:otherwise>` element is reached. Once an `<xsl:when>` or `<xsl:otherwise>` element is chosen, the `<xsl:choose>` block is exited. No explicit break or exit statement is required.

It's remarkably similar to a `switch` statement from C inspired languages (C, C++, Java, C#) or [`Select...Case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) from Visual Basic

The [`xsl:if`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256209.aspx) doesn't have the equivalent from such languages of an `else` clause, so I'd only recommend it if you want to either do "something" or not (I.e. in the not case, you don't want to specify an alternative)

Comment: I think "ensure that their conditions are mutually exclusive" seems to say the opposite of what you mean. The `when` clauses of a `choose` element are mutually exclusive. Two distinct `if` elements can both evaluate to true, and hence are *not* mutually exclusive. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @senderle - yes, I was trying to say that you can only *substitute* `xsl:if`s where you're currently using an `xsl:choose` *if* you're willing to ensure that the conditions are mutually exclusive. If you do not do so, then as we say, multiple `if`s may match and so the `xsl:if` based version and the `xsl:choose` versions have different semantics.